# Where is `List.map` defined?

Tags: .net-core, f#

I've been looking for the implementation of `List.map` in F#. The [code in `list.fs` in `dotnet/fsharp` on GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/fsharp/blob/ae2fe52d269a822ca773137c85f3f6deb8b76b1c/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/list.fs#L74) delegates to a mysterious `Microsoft.FSharp.Primitives.Basics.List.map` function.

Where is the source of that function? I can't find any such directory path in the repo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think [this](https://github.com/dotnet/fsharp/blob/ae2fe52d269a822ca773137c85f3f6deb8b76b1c/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/local.fs#L241) is it:

```ml
    let map mapping x =
        match x with
        | [] -> []
        | [h] -> [mapping h]
        | h :: t ->
            let cons = freshConsNoTail (mapping h)
            mapToFreshConsTail cons mapping t
            cons
```

Comment: I updated the link to be a permalink which is tied to a commit.